# Python function to create and manipulate lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a function that takes a number as an argument. This function is supposed to create a copy of an existing list(of 100 elements), and then manipulate a value in the list chosen at random. If i give the function an argument of 200, for example, it has to create a new list and choose a value at random every single time, making sure that in the 200 times it creates new lists, each element in the original existing list of 100 elements is manipulated at least once. This data will be graphed later on. I keep noticing that the function that I wrote is not manipulating every single element. My code is as follows:

```
def condition_manipulate(value):
    list_set=[]
    for i in range(0,value):
        new_list=initial_conditions[:]
        x=random.choice(new_list)
        variable=new_sum(new_list.index(x))             #new_sum is a pre-defined function
        new_list[new_list.index(x)]=variable
        list_set.append(new_list)
    return list_set
```

The problem might be that I chose random.choice, and this is not letting condition_manipulate run on 
every single element in initial_conditions at least once, but what could I do to fix this?

EDIT: I just graphed my data and noticed that it keeps on running on the same value in new_list... It isn't choosing any other value!

Comment: Could you please be clearer as you to what you want. I find your question confusion. Try saying what you want in bullet points.

Comment: For the number I enter into the function, condition_manipulate, I need it to copy the list, initial_conditions, that many number of times. So, now i have the initial list, and a bunch of copies. I need the function to then choose a random value in each list, making sure it is choosing each index at least once, yet at random. So, the first time it runs, it might choose the 65th index from a copied list. the next time it runs, it might choose the 45th index from the next copied list....

Comment: i need the function to do this for each copied list, given that it needs to choose each index at least once

Comment: Might I suggest that you create a separate list to take into account the numbers already chosen. The problem is that, I can solve this problem for you, but then you won't figure it out yourself, and I think you can.

Comment: I think I have figured out my problem. Every single time the function creates a copy of the original list, the function is then choosing the same value in each list, and then running the new_sum function on the same index corresponding to the value.

Comment: I will try to modify my code. If it works, I will let you know. If not, then I will keep on working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be that `new_list[new_list.index(x)]=variable` assigns to the first `x` in the list, which is not necessarily the chosen `x`. Try:

```
import random

def condition_manipulate(value):
    list_set=[]
    for i in range(value):
        new_list=initial_conditions[:]
        i=random.choice(range(len(initial_conditions)))
        new_list[i]=new_sum(new_list[i])
        list_set.append(new_list)
    return list_set
```

Randomness aside, working with indices is more efficient than searching the entire list for `x` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

From the way I see things. You are creating a list of values, and then choosing a random number from that list. Now, your question seems to be that you want a random or rather a different number each time.

It is not improbable that you get not all numbers are manipulated, after all, this is random. However, you might want to graph this, and see if all the members are changed as you increase the number of loops. Even after that, if not all your values are manipulated, then you might have a problem with your algorithm.

So, an easy way to do this would be using matplotlib.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I graphed and noticed that it keeps on choosing the same value every single time from the initial list

Comment: Try using `random.randint()` instead, and passing in the list as one of your parameters.